# Executing shell script from web page

Tags: linux, bash, shell, php

I am fairly new to php, but I was trying to use php to launch a shell script.

When I use php /var/www/html/indexes.php it works, but when I load up the webpage the shell script does not do all of what it is meant to.

PHP file:

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('sh /home/user/Desktop/script.sh');
echo $result; (just to make sure it fired)
?>
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
sudo -u user nautilus
```

When I fire the php through the console it works, but when I load the webpage up it does not. I have run chmod +x on both the php and shell scripts, with no luck. It returns the Hello World, but does not fire up the nautilus as the user. I don't know but maybe it has something to do with the X server? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You using in your shell script command `sudo` that supposed to ask a password for elevated privilege. Either you need to disable passwords on `sudo` (which is a bad idea) and add web user (www, or www-data or one who runs `php` from web) to the group of `sudo` or rethink your task, it pretty dangerous to giving  access from web to the root's privileges

Comment: have you check error.log/access.log ?

Comment: Don't use `sudo` - apart from being dangerous, it's likely (depending on configuration) to drop environment variables such as `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` that will be needed by the X11 application.

Answer (score 0):

For using the system commands on webpages through php you have to provide full path to the command from where it stored.

For example

```
>/usr/bin/nautilius [parameter]
```